# Run Shell Script as SystemD Service in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, systemd, root

I tried to run these command

```
$ nano /usr/bin/script.sh 
$ chmod +x /usr/bin/script.sh
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/shellscript.service 
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

$ systemctl daemon-reload 
$ systemctl enable shellscript.service 
$ systemctl start shellscript.service
```

but when checking on the service status, I got:

```
$ systemctl status shellscript.service

shellscript.service - My Shell Script
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/shellscript.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-05-23 13:20:33 EEST; 14s ago
    Process: 1276 ExecStart=/usr/bin/script.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    Main PID: 1276 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 10ms
May 23 13:20:33 kali systemd[1]: Started My Shell Script. 
May 23 13:20:33 kali script.sh[1276]: /usr/bin/script.sh: line 25: AthanMayT.txt: No such file or directory 
May 23 13:20:33 kali systemd[1]: shellscript.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
May 23 13:20:33 kali systemd[1]: shellscript.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: what's the content of `/usr/bin/script.sh`?

Answer (score 5):

Your `shellscript.service` definition is working. The shell script was executed, but some command on line #25 of the script returned an error message:

```
AthanMayT.txt: No such file or directory
```

This caused the script to exit with status code 1, indicating a failure.

Errors like this are often caused by the current working directory not being what you expected.

You should note that any process or script executed by `systemd` is not normally executed in any user's home directory: the default working directory for any process started by systemd will be the system's root directory, or `/`.

To troubleshoot, run your script like this to simulate the conditions when executed by systemd:

```
cd /
/usr/bin/script.sh
```

You should probably use full pathnames for every file you reference in your script, or explicitly include a `cd /full/path/to/some/directory` in the beginning of the script to ensure that relative path names are interpreted the way you expect.